# Saving markdown content on server

Tags: javascript, markdown

I am using [PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) to save markdown content on a website.

My question is: how should i save the content on the server for futhere display / edit?

Should i save the markdown content, the html result, or both?

Comment: Personally, I'd save the just the content.  I feel this is rather an opinion based question though.

Comment: If i save the content, i will need a markdown engine everytime i need to display the result?

Comment: Yes, you will.  Depending on your environment and use case, you may need to store the html result as well.  This is why it's rather opinion based and depends entirely on the wider context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save just the markdown content.

- If you saved just the html result a user would not be able to edit the content directly.
- If you saved both it's true that you wouldn't need the markdown engine for displaying html but that comes at the expense of data duplication in your database. Data duplication isn't "wrong" pre say but it increases risk of coding mistakes ( i.e. what if markdown content and html result don't match  due to some database query mistake).